# How to pass model data between view controllers using the same model object

Tags: ios, swift, segue

In ViewController A (ParameterViewController), I created a `Parameter Model` that takes in the following:

```
Parameter(name: "Alkalinity", symbol: "Kh", productName: ["item one", "item two", "item three"])
```

View Controller A displays a collection view cell and in the cell parameter name and symbol is used. When the user taps a cell (alkalinity), I want to pass the productName array to view controller B.

I think I may be faulty In my model, but here is what I did so far.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let productViewController = segue.destination as? ProductSelectionViewController else {
      fatalError()
    }

    if segue.identifier == productSegueIdentifier {
      if let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0]
        let productList = parameters[indexPath.item] as Parameter
        print("The Product List Is: \(productList)")
        let productNames: [String] = productList.productName
        print("The Product Names are \(productNames)")
        productViewController.products = productNames
      }
    }
  }
```

View Controller B (ProductViewController) looks like this.

```
class ProductSelectionViewController: UITableViewController {
  var products = [String]()
  let identifier = "ProductCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
      let productItem = products[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel?.text = productItem
      return cell
    }
```

I feel that since I declare product as `[String]` it is horrible architecture. When I declare it as Parameter I get the error cannot assign Parameter to type String

Comment: I wouldn't use the segue to pass the model data. The data should be fetched from a Model singleton or provided by a Coordinator. Segues make mess and can be used only to pass small pieces of data like the number of the selector row. That's just my opinion shaped by practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your issue by creating your model as follows:

```
struct Parameter {
    var name : String
    var symbol: String
    var productsName: [ProductsName]
}

struct ProductsName {
    var productName: String
}
```

Create two model where first one for your parameter model and second one for your product name list.

Then after pass your parameter as product, no need will not be horrible architecture.

In `ViewController A`, update following line of code:

```
let productNames: [ProductsName] = productList.productsName
```

In `ViewController B`, update following line of code:

```
var products = [ProductsName]()
```

then after after access name by:

```
products[indexPath.row].productName
```

I hope this will be solution what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We should avoid creating string arrays inside our model because they are not scalable in future. Instead create you model parameter like

```
struct Paramerter {
  name: String?
  symbol: String?
  products: [Product]?
}

struct Product {
  name: String?
}
```

Now initialize your Parameter model in View controller A as

```
let product1 = Product(name:"item one")
let product2 = Product(name:"item two")
let product3 = Product(name:"item three")
Parameter(name: "Alkalinity", symbol: "Kh", products: [product1, product2, product3])
```

Your segue method will remain same. View Controller B (ProductViewController) looks like

```
class ProductSelectionViewController: UITableViewController {
  var products: [Product]?
  let identifier = "ProductCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
      let productItem = products[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel?.text = productItem?.name
      return cell
    }
}
```

Now your Product model is fully scalable, If in future it need to add any more items like product description, product Id etc so you just need to update your Product model and you are ready to get set values from your Product model array.

Comment: This won’t work because there are about 50 products for each parameter.